# how to share code in workflowLibs in Jenkins using workflow plugin

Tags: jenkins-workflow

In my **workflowLibs** directory I have a few files:

```
src/org/inin/Pipeline.groovy
src/org/inin/Build.groovy
src/org/inin/Test.groovy
```

The **Build.groovy** look like this:

```
package org.inin;

def DoBuild(foo){
  echo "I am building: $foo"
}
```

The **Test.groovy** look like this:

```
package org.inin;

def DoTest(foo){
  echo "I am testing: $foo"
}
```

I want my builds to do something like this:

```
def pipeline =  new org.inin.Pipeline()
pipeline.DoBuild() or pipeline.Build.DoBuild()
pipeline.DoTest()  or pipeline.Test.DoTest()
```

But I don't know how to make the Pipeline.groovy reference files in it's own directory.
I tried doing this:

```
package org.inin;
load "Build.groovy"
//evaluate(new File("./Build.groovy"))
```

But I always get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method DoBuild found among ...
```

What's the proper way to do share code among groovy files in the **workflowLibs** directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing some hackery:

**src/org/inin/Pipeline.groovy:**

```
package org.inin;

def getBuild(){
 return new Build();
}

def getTest(){
 return new Test();
}
```

**src/org/inin/Build.groovy:**

```
package org.inin;

def DoMavenBuild(gitRepo, gitBranch, pomName ){
    ...
}
```

**src/org/inin/Test.groovy:**

```
package org.inin;

def DoTest(){
    ...
}
```

And in the job itself:

```
def pipeline =  new org.inin.Pipeline();
pipeline.build.DoMavenBuild(...);
pipeline.test.DoTest();
```

Comment: Not sure why you call that “hackery”, just looks like straightforward Groovy code to me.